# Xamarin Android Project failed to create

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

When I am creating a `DroidBlankAppApplication`, Visual Studio just says 'Creating project 'App1'... project creation failed.' There is no details in the Output window. No errors in the error window. And I can't find anywhere to see what the exact issue is.

Comment: try repairing visual studio

Comment: There is something wrong when you install your `Xamarin`,  refer to 
 this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/windows/#vs2017